# Use X:Array to store WPF ComboBox Image items

Tags: c#, wpf

I define two dimensional XAML arrays in a Resource Dictionary to store WPF ComboBox data content as follows....

```
 <x:Array x:Key="ThreatLevelArray" Type="{x:Type local:ThreatLevel}">
    <local:ThreatLevel ThreatLevelName="Very Low" ThreatLevelNumber="0" />
    <local:ThreatLevel ThreatLevelName="Low" ThreatLevelNumber="1" />
</x:Array>
```

The array is supported by this class in the code-behind...

```
public class ThreatLevel
{
    public int ThreatLevelNumber { get; set; }
    public string ThreatLevelName { get; set; }
}
```

The ComboBox displays "ThreatLevelName" and updates the field "ThreatLevel" in the database with the value provided by "ThreatLevelNumber".

```
<ComboBox x:Name="threatLevelComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="ThreatLevelName" IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource ThreatLevelArray}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ThreatLevel, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
          SelectedValuePath="ThreatLevelNumber"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" />
```

That all works, but I want to be able to display an image instead of the "ThreatLevelName" text.  I have tried ....

```
public class ThreatLevel
{
    public int ThreatLevelNumber { get; set; }
    public string ThreatLevelName { get; set; }
    public Image ThreatLevelImage { get; set; }
}
```

But the following gives me the error "The TypeConverter for "Image" does not support converting from a string".

```
 <x:Array x:Key="ThreatLevelArray" Type="{x:Type local:ThreatLevel}">
    <local:ThreatLevel ThreatLevelName="Very Low" ThreatLevelNumber="0" ThreatLevelImage="/RMS_EF6;component/RMS_Images/VeryLow.png"/>
    <local:ThreatLevel ThreatLevelName="Low" ThreatLevelNumber="1" ThreatLevelImage="/RMS_EF6;component/RMS_Images/Low.png"/>
</x:Array>
```

How can I resolve this error and use this procedure to create a ComboBox like the following ....

```
<ComboBox x:Name="threatLevelComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="ThreatLevelImage" IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource ThreatLevelArray}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ThreatLevel, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
          SelectedValuePath="ThreatLevelNumber"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML parser converts an image path string to a `BitmapFrame`, not to an `Image` element. This is done by implicit type conversion from string to `ImageSource`, performed by the `ImageSourceConverter` class.

Use `ImageSource` as property type of your `ThreatLevelImage` property

```
public class ThreatLevel
{
    public int ThreatLevelNumber { get; set; }
    public string ThreatLevelName { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ThreatLevelImage { get; set; }
}
```

and instead of setting `DisplayMemberPath`, use an `Image` element in the `ItemTemplate` of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding ThreatLevelImage}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: What a champion,  and on a Saturday too.  Many thanks.